# Change user control's objects properties from properties panel in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, binding, properties

How could I enable to edit the properties of my user control in the properties window of visual studio. Let me show you what I mean:

here I have a date Picker control and note how I can modify the date and other properties within the properties window:

[image]

An here I have a simple user control that just consists of two textblocks in order to produce a glow effect:

[image]

So when I place that user control on my main window how could I modify the text withing the properties window in visual studio?

[image]

It will be nice if I could create a custom property that will be visible in that property window just like the date picker control. I change the properties of that user control with code when the window loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [example](http://dev-for-fun.blogspot.com/2008/06/wpf-example-create-usercontrol-and.html).  It may be that you need to define dependency properties in addition to standard .net properties.  You might want to post your C# code, too.